# How to run a delayed_job?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, delayed-job

I am trying to run a job in delayed_jobs .I used the syntax "Mailer.delay.somefunction()".It is present in the delayed_jobs table in the database but doesnt execute.How can i make it run or why it is not running?

Comment: Anything in the logs?

Comment: No.It didnt execute since there were a lot of jobs pending in the delayed_jobs.I created this task in a seperate queue.Even then its not running..How can i make this task to run in a seperate thread so that it executes faster and doesnt bother other jobs?

Comment: You may want to look into delayed_job's queues. You can have an email queue and then another for your other jobs.

Comment: So if i just create a separate queue for the task,will it allocate a separate worker? If so ,how can i find which worker is doing which work.Thanks!

Comment: I wanted the console commands to manually invoke it.I found it (Delayed::Job.find(id).invoke_job)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found some useful commands for manually invoking the delayed_jobs from the queue.

```
Delayed::Job.find(id).invoke_job
Delayed::Worker.new.run(Delayed::Job.last)
```